# python dict comprehension with two ranges

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I'm trying to produce some code that produces for example:

`{1:7,2:8,3:9,4:10}`

and

`{i:j for i in range(1,5) for j in range(7,11)}`

produces

`{1: 10, 2: 10, 3: 10, 4: 10}`

how can I fix it?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> dict(zip(range(1,5), range(7,11)))
{1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}
```

Using [*dict comprehension*](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
>>> {k:v for k, v in zip(range(1,5), range(7,11))}
{1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}

>>> {x:x+6 for x in range(1,5)}
{1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}
```

### Why your code does not work:

Your code is similar to following code:

```
ret = {}
for i in range(1,5):
    for j in range(7,11):
        ret[i] = j
    # ret[i] = 10 is executed at last for every `i`.
```

Comment: You could take the upper bound off the second one and use `itertools.count(7)` instead...

Comment: @JonClements, Ashwini Chaudhary's answer address that. Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
{i: j for i, j in zip(range(1, 5), range(7, 11))}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)(or `itertools.izip`) and `itertools.count`:

```
>>> from itertools import count, izip
```

Dict-comprehension:

```
>>> {k:v for k,v in izip(xrange(1,5), count(7))}
{1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}
```

`dict()`:

```
>>> dict(izip(xrange(1,5), count(7)))
{1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> dict(enumerate(range(7, 11), 1))
{1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}
```